# Fail test run if Common Test suite cannot be compiled

Tags: erlang, common-test

If I have a syntax error in one of my Common Test suites, `ct_run` simply waits for 15 seconds and then continues. It displays this message:

```
{error,make_failed}

Failed to compile or locate one or more test suites
Press 'c' to continue or 'a' to abort.
Will continue in 15 seconds if no answer is given!
(c/a)
```

If I use `-noshell`, then it displays:

```
{error,make_failed}
```

...and continues anyway.

How do I make it **abort** if compilation fails?

Comment: Won't `ct_run -erl_args -noshell` disable any interaction?

Comment: Yes, but it still continues...

Comment: Have you tried option `-abort_if_missing_suites` with `-noshell`?

Comment: Hm, seems I've misunderstood original question. So yah, both options needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/common_test/src/ct_run.erl#L1765). When ct_run encounters compilation error, it tries to ask you, whether you want to continue. `continue/2` function does a [dirty trick](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/common_test/src/ct_run.erl#L2107) in order to determine if tests are run interactively. But you are able to cheat this function passing `-noshell` emulator option. In this case, `continue/2` function will [make decision](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/common_test/src/ct_run.erl#L2104) based on `-abort_if_missing_suites`.

So, you need to `ct_run -abort_if_missing_suites -erl_args -noshell`.

Comment: Note that this requires Erlang 17.0 or newer; we're still using Erlang R16B03-1 at the moment.

Comment: Oops. That's interesting. I didn't peek into elder versions code.

Comment: In 18.2, you no longer need the `-noshell` option to make `-abort_if_missing_suites` work (but we're still using 17.x...)

Comment: Important note (because I made this mistake): it only works if you put it _before_ `-erl_args`.